# Swift - Overloading "+" Operator - "Cannot Convert Value of type" Error

Tags: swift, overloading, operator-keyword

I'm hitting a compiler error that is best illustrated by the small code snippet below.
[image]

**My goal is be able to perform addition on instances of `MyEnum` directly along side `CGFloat`.**

Now for simple cases this works perfectly fine however for more complex statements as seen in `let three` example below it causes a compiler error.

I have a feeling the issue is coming down the precedence (compiler can't decide to evaluate the first+second parts first or the second+third parts first) but I'm not sure. I've tried several variations including,

- Moving the operator functions to global scope.
- Moving the two operator functions that take `CGFloat` arguments to an `extension CGFloat` instead.

Here is an boiled down code snippet that illustrates the issue.

```
enum MyEnum {
   case someOption

   var value: CGFloat { ... }
}

extension MyEnum {
    static func + (left: MyEnum, right: MyEnum) -> CGFloat {
        return left.value + right.value
    }
    static func + (left: MyEnum, right: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return left.value + right
    }
    static func + (left: CGFloat, right: MyEnum) -> CGFloat {
        return left + right.value
    }
}

let one = MyEnum.someOption + 1
let two = MyEnum.someOption + MyEnum.someOption
let three = MyEnum.someOption + MyEnum.someOption + MyEnum.someOption // fails
let four = (MyEnum.someOption + MyEnum.someOption) + MyEnum.someOption // also fails
```

To add more confusion if I create a completely new custom operator called `•` for example and I mark it part of the `AdditionPrecedence` group everything works totally fine. Ultimately I want the `+` operator to make thing intuitive.

```
enum MyEnum {
    case someOption

    var value: CGFloat { ... }
}

infix operator •: AdditionPrecedence

extension MyEnum {
    static func • (left: MyEnum, right: MyEnum) -> CGFloat {
        return left.value + right.value
    }
    static func • (left: MyEnum, right: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return left.value + right
    }
    static func • (left: CGFloat, right: MyEnum) -> CGFloat {
        return left + right.value
    }
}

let one = MyEnum.someOption • 1
let two = MyEnum.someOption • MyEnum.someOption
let three = MyEnum.someOption • MyEnum.someOption • MyEnum.someOption // works totally fine now
```

## UPDATE

The code snippet above is just for illustration purposes. My actual implementation has several attributes that rule out some of suggestions I'm getting like using `static let` or `enums` with a `RawValue`. For example, some of our cases have associated values, etc. I'd really love some discussion on the issue I've isolated rather than alternatives to my psudo-architecture!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for why this is happening.

I also don't understand what purpose does this API design solve. Usually when we provide operator overloads, it is to provide convenience for your own type (the type that is providing the overload).

In other words, you stick to your type (NOT move away from it). In this case it seems like we are moving away from it.

I know it does not answer your question, here's how we would stick to the type (instead of moving away).

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum MyEnum {
    case one
}

extension MyEnum {
    static func + (left: MyEnum, right: MyEnum) -> MyEnum {
        return .one
    }
    static func + (left: MyEnum, right: CGFloat) -> MyEnum {
        return .one
    }
    static func + (left: CGFloat, right: MyEnum) -> MyEnum {
        return .one
    }
}

let one = MyEnum.one + MyEnum.one
let two = MyEnum.one + 1
let three = 1 + MyEnum.one

let one1 = MyEnum.one + MyEnum.one + MyEnum.one
let two1 = 1 + MyEnum.one + 1
let three1 = MyEnum.one + 1 + MyEnum.one
```

###### Why is this happening only for `+` and not for `•`?

> My guess would be `+` is in a lot of places throughout the standard library, so which version of `CGFloat`'s `+` overload it is conflicting with, we can't say.
>
> As soon as you limit it's scope to your own `MyEnum` type, it compiles as you'd expect.
>
> In case of `•`, it gives you a clean state, it's nowhere to be found in standard library, so no conflicts.

As I said, this is a speculation and if you really want to dig into why exactly this is happening, [Swift Forums](https://forums.swift.org/) might be a better place for this discussion.

---

#### UPDATE

> We have an `enum` that defines our design language's standard set of spacings. It's often required that we need to perform arithmetic on attributes of UI elements such as `width` and our custom spacing enum. My goal is take make writing these statements as seamless as possible.

I would do this with a case-less `enum` (just used for namespacing) with a set  of hard coded spacing values like following.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

enum Dimens {
    static let one: CGFloat = 1
    static let two: CGFloat = 2
    static let four: CGFloat = 4
    static let six: CGFloat = 6
    static let eight: CGFloat = 8
    static let ten: CGFloat = 10
}

// The call site still looks the same
// There's nothing between what UIKit requires and what you are supplying
// Your enum is completely invisible, no overloads needed
let stackView = UIStackView()
stackView.spacing = Dimens.eight
```

Comment: Thanks for response! As far as the purpose I intentionally kept that vague to focus on the issue at heart. We have a an `enum` that defines our design language's standard set of spacings. It's often required that we need to perform arithmetic on attributes of UI elements such as `width` and our custom spacing enum. My goal is take make writing these statements as seamless as possible. It's not possible to "stick to my custom type" as you suggest as nearly all statements you can form do not have a valid `MyEnum` option as the result.

I did cross post in Swift Forums!

Comment: @anders Thanks for sharing the use case, please see the **UPDATE**.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond again, I appreciate it. I'm realizing need to provide some more information in my question. Unfortunately that solution isn't going to work for me! See my appended update